# monitoring which processes executing in dedicated cpu cores

Tags: linux

I know I can perf to record what's happening  in core 2 using :

```
perf  record -e  sched:sched_switch -C 2
```

I am curious if there is another tool like top or else , allow me to stare at the screen and monitor what pid(s) executing in core 2 ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349908/how-to-get-all-processes-running-on-each-cpu-core-in-ubuntu), but the short answer is this:
Using `ps -e -o psr,pid,%cpu,%mem,args` you can get the (virtual) core used under the `PSR` column, and you can grep for a certain core (in this case `10`) with:

```sh
ps -e -o psr,pid,%cpu,%mem,args | grep -E '^(PSR|[[:space:]]*10)'
```

This gives you output like this: [image: command output]

If you want to monitor in real-time you can run the command in a while loop like this, replacing `10` with the core of your choice:

```sh
while true; do clear; ps -e -o psr,pid,%cpu,%mem,args | grep -E '^(PSR|[[:space:]]*10 )'; sleep 2; done
```

You can also add a `PROCESSOR` column to `top`: go into top, press `f` to open the Fields Management menu and choose `P` (last used CPU). You can then filter for processor core by pressing `o` and typing in: `P=8`, replacing `8` with the core you want to monitor.